# Check the type of data sent/received in java on network

Tags: java, network-programming, file-transfer, fileinputstream

I have a simple java peer-to-peer chat program which works fine. I want to add a feature in this program. I want to enable the users to send files also over the network.

Currently with the simple chatting, I don't have to worry about the type or data that is sent or received/sent by the user. But with the file transfer capability I have to know what type of data (whether a file or plain text) is being sent so that if the its plain text I can simply show it to the user but with the file I have to open a JFilechooser or some kind of dialog box to receive or send the file.
The following is the code at the receiving end

```
try {
        incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(css.getInputStream()));

        String receive = new String();
        String history = "";
        String name = incoming.readLine();
        chatWindow.RemoteField.setText(name);

        do {
            receive = incoming.readLine();
            history = history + "\n" + receive;
            if (receive != null) {
                chatWindow.recm.setText(history);
            } else {
                receive = "BYE";
            }

            //System.out.println("Received Message: "+receive);

        } while (receive.equals("BYE") != true);
    } catch (Exception npe) {
        System.out.println("Error2" + npe);
    }
```

So how can I add checking of type of data that is received before showing it to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send some value that indicates what the next item of data is going to be.  For example, you could precede each text line with a value of `TEXT\n`, and for each file `FILE:nnn\n` where `\n` is the newline character and `nnn` is the file size in bytes, so you know how much of the stream to read before expecting another `TEXT` or `FILE` marker.

**UPDATE**

For example, your incoming stream might look like:

```
TEXT
Hey mate, here's some cool file
FILE:10
1234
56789TEXT
Did you get it ok?
```

I'm assuming a chat message will only ever be one line of text.  Also, the file doesn't need to be terminated with a line return because the number of bytes is already known, 10 in the example above (including the new line character between 4 and 5).  The contents of the file here is:

```
1234
56789
```

Comment: So you mean to say I should add two unique padding before the text and the file and the identify the type of data based on the padding. Right?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the clearest way of telling the client what type of data to expect.